# Using PHP to mySQL query SELECT COUNT

Tags: php, mysql, select, count

I am trying to use mySQL query with data from POST. I am a total beginner. The issue is the script do not print me any results of the query.

Here is the form:

```
<form method="post" action="add.php">
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td width="100">Data dd/mm/rr</td>
<td><input name="data" type="date" id="data"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">First</td>
<td><input name="first" type="text" id="first" maxlength="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Second</td>
<td><input name="second" type="text" id="second" maxlength="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td>
<input name="add" type="submit" id="add" value="Add">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

And here is add.php

```
<html>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<head>
  <title>Lottery</title>
</head>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$value = $_POST['Value'];  
echo "Chosen value : " .$value;  
}

?>


<div class="results">
<p>Counter: <? echo "".$value ?></p>
<p>Place: <? echo "".$value ?>: </p>
<p>Best match<? echo "".$value ?> :</p>
</div>



    <?
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "lottery_root";
$password = "xyz";
$database = "lottery";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database) or die(mysqli_error($conn));



$result = mysqli_query($conn, "Select count(*) from lottery where first='$_SESSION[value]' or      second='$_SESSION[value]'; ");
if (!$result) echo mysqli_error($conn);

$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
print_r($row);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

@MMK
It looks like this and works better this is what it prints.  Array ( [0] => 0 ) But 0 is not the correct value. Doesnt matter how many records match this query it always return 0. There is connection to db and queries are executing because when I use for example SELECT * FROM lottery; it prints whole record, but just one, not all of it.

Comment: Don't mixed up `mysql` and `mysqli` together.

Answer (score 1):

I don't find any field with `name="Value"`

As in add.php you are expecting some value in  `$_POST['Value']` since there is no field with this name so `$_POST['Value']` is not even set.

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed up `mysql_*` functions with `mysqli_*`. Next thing: You missed fourth parameter in MySQL connection (when creating new Mysqli object). Aaand, don't use PHP short tags, they are deprecated. Instead of using `<?` use `<?php`.

Second thing, how do You set `value` key to session? Maybe You should use `$_POST` global array in Your query.

Try this:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username   = "lottery_root";
$password   = "xyz";
$database   = "xxx";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM lottery WHERE first='".$_POST['first']."' or druga='".$_POST['second']."' ");

if (!$result) {
    echo $conn->error;
}

$row = $result->fetch_row();

print_r($row);


$conn->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have use **mysqli** for connections while you are not using **$conn** obj in firing query.

try this

```
$value = $_SESSION['value'];
if($result = $conn->query("select count(*) from lottery where first='$value' or druga='$value'")){
  if(mysqli_num_row($result) > 0){
     $row = mysqli_fetch_object($results);
     print_r($row);
  }
}else{
    print_r($conn->error)
}
$conn->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `mysqli` to connect and using `mysql` to get data. Secondly why are you not selecting `database`?

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "lottery_root";
$password = "xyz";
$db = "yourDB";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "Select count(*) from lottery where first='$_SESSION[value]' or second='$_SESSION[value]'; ");
if (!$result) echo mysqli_error($conn);

$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
print_r($row);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

it should be

```
<?php echo "".$value ?>
```

not

```
<? echo "".$value ?>
```